# How Play YouTube video in webBrowser control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to play YouTube video in webBrowser control? Because when i tap on watch video nothing happens...

Thanks!

Comment: have you installed YouTube on the phone? AFAIK it is responsible for handling YouTube videos.

Comment: I wanted to watch videos inside of my application

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Windows Phone 7 does not support Flash yet.

Take a look at this:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/will-windows-phone-7-play-you-tube-and-flash/29c69dc1-658f-4729-b24d-67b46a4138d2